# How to pass key to datastore object

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have done this before and it worked. But today, it’s not working.

Here is my entity

```
class MyPage(ndb.Model):
  page = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
```

Then to create an entity I do

```
myPage = MyPage(id=“some_id_string”)
```

But this line keeps throwing an exception

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument id
```

So I try

```
myPage = MyPage(key_name=“some_id_string”)
```

and I got the same error.

So how do I pass a custom key to my datastore entity in python?

Comment: Is __init__() method defined for your class or you are using the default?

Comment: What class? I am already showing `MyPage` above

Comment: Your code is correct, you need to provide full error stack trace to look further.